# Memcached problem with Rails 3. Object isn't being deserialized the second time around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I'm having a problem using memcached in Rails 3

The following is in my controller

`@last_post = Rails.cache.fetch('last') {Post.last}`

From the view I call `@last_post.title`

The first time the view is loaded, the title of the last post is displayed. Once the view is refreshed, I get the error `undefined method 'title' for #<String:0x8007ae0>`

It seems like the object isn't being deserialized the second time around.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to fix this? (Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think its to do with Marshal.load, basically rails magically loads all the classes for you but when you call Rails.cache.fetch at some point it will call Marshal.load which doesn’t know anything about the Rails dependency loading and can sometimes silently fail(undefined class/module)

My solution is to simply add

```
require_dependency 'post'
```

to your controller which should load the class for the Marshal library to see

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!  Make sure you have your store set in your `development.rb` regardless if you have caching on or not. Aka add this to `development.rb`

`config.cache_store = :dalli_store`